# Regex password to allow special characters javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using the following regex (got it from here) to verify passwords:

```
/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z]{6,}$/
```

I'm not too familiar with regexpressions, but how would I allow this to allow for special characters like !@#$%^&*?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add the other characters you want to the part inside the brackets.

The resulting regex is:

### `/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z!@#$%^&*?]{6,}$/`

[Regex101 Tested](https://regex101.com/r/vA5cE1/1)

Answer (score 1):

I think that this regular expression `/^[\w!@#\$%\^&\*\?]{8,}$/` will match what you need if the all the special characters you want to include are the ones you mentioned and you want a password of at least 8 characters.

Comment: No, this breaks the password requirements that the first regex had.

Comment: Also, there's no need to escape special characters with a ``\`` from inside a character class. Character classes always interpret their contents literally with the exception of things like `\w`